# Many errors when using Oraclize (Remix with Mist)

Tags: oracles

Hi when I use Remix with Mist, I get these error with Oraclize. How do I solve it?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an issue with Solidity 0.4.12. Abstract contracts such as ERC-20 even fail and many others. This was fixed by the Solidity team in 0.4.13

Answer (score 0):

I realised I have to use a older version of the compiler to compile it.